# MySQL error with load data infile fixed by reboot?

Tags: mysql, file-upload

I've got an Ubuntu server where there's a task to import a csv file.  Generally everything runs smoothly but every once in a while I get an error:

```
Mysql::Error: 
The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: 
\n LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

I don't think the error is accurate as the same import script runs most of the time. Rebooting the server and rerunning the script "fixes" the issue.  Still, that doesn't seem like a long-term solution.  What else could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

what version of mysql do you have ?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

try reading this thread, it may be helpful. The guy seemds to have similar problem solved.

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=65260